# How to abstract a group of views

Tags: android

For my project I want to create a row that has several items of this type:
[image: my custom view]

Once I have this "base" layout / view setup I want to be able to use it on several occasions to handle different types of actions such as:
A Save button with the text as "Save" and the image as a star or a share button with the text as "share" and the image as the share icon

So ultimately I want to abstract this custom view to allow me to do this.

Some things I have seen to do this have been `<include>` , `<merge>` and creating a custom view class.

My thoughts about each of this are:

`<include>` : This doesn't really allow for me to be able to customize the content of the included layout, only to reuse some common xml

`<merge>` : Similarly this doesn't offer the customization aspect

Custom View class : I am not writing a view that does something that is not offered from android by default (like adding a pie chart view or something) rather I am just combining a group of already implemented views. I do think that this method could solve my problem I am just not sure if it is the right way.

In reality I know that three views is not much code to reproduce each time I use it but I thought it would be useful to figure out a way to abstract this group

Comment: The `<merge>` tag can actually be customized. You can set your own attributes and use them when the `View` gets drawn. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) are the details

Answer (score 0):

Create you own class is the best.

```
class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Later  define custom attributes.

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="MyClass">
       <attr name="xxx" format="boolean" />
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

remember add  in your project.

Comment: Why do you say this "is the best" approach to solving this? Are there other feasible approaches?